# treeview node selection always return first Node of Tree, instead of selected one

Tags: c#, excel, treeview, treenode

I am working on C# Project [**Windows Form Application**], to update treeview nodes from excelsheet [xls] Cell [row i, Column 3] Values, while on selecting treenode, it should update corresponding Column 4 Value [row i, Column 4].
For me, Treenode are populated successfully, but on selecting the treenode, it always display first Element of treenode [Not selected one].

Populated Treenode from Excel as:
[ Update Child Nodes from Column 3 elements [Column 2 Contain Parent node    name and Column 3 have  Child Node name], if Column 2 Value is same as Parent node name [My Module], update the child nodeunder same Parent node.]

```
            for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string mynode = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3]).Value2.ToString();
                string mynode2 = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2]).Value2.ToString();

                if (mynode2 == mymodule)
                {
                    TreeNode ChildNode = ParentNode.Nodes.Add(mynode);
                    ChildNode.Text = mynode;
                }                    
            }
```

On selecting the Child Node, it always give 1st Parent node. Instead of Selected Node.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2; i++)            
        {                
string mynodetext = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3]).Value2.ToString();
 string mynodetext1 = ((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 4]).Value2.ToString();

        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.FirstNode.Text == mynodetext)
       {
          this.richTextBox1.SelectedText += Environment.NewLine + mynodetext1 + Environment.NewLine;
       }
      }
```

Please Guide, How to get correct selected Node.

Comment: What about trying treeView1.SelectedItem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
treeView1.SelectedItem
```

to access the value. Just keep in mind that this is a read only property compared to listbox and combobox controls.

Comment: Sorry Vidas, I am using Windows Form Application and i am not getting treeView1.SelectedItems (Sorry for wrong info), please if you can guide.